# Angular call API when data is updated

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
   private imgs;

if (typeof this.imgs === "undefined") {
      this.imgs = await this.api.createData(
        this.currentData,
        configuartion
      );
    }
```

Hi, I have code above it works quite fine unless I update my `currentData` and want to call `this.api.createData(this.currentData,configuration)` again. How can I do it? is there rxjs I can use there to detect changes or I can do it some other way?

updated:

`this.imgs` contains array of objects i want to call api again if array is updated

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ngDoCheck()` lifecycle hook. In this case you need to define oldData similar to currentData to hold earlier version of data.
It would something look like below:

```
ngDoCheck(){
  if(!this.currentData.equals(this.oldData)) {
    this.oldData = this.currentData;
    //your code to call API
  }
}
```